# Collider2D not detecting collisions at all unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 2 player fighting game in unity and am using boxcollider2Ds for attack hitboxes and compositecollider2Ds for defending hitboxes. One time I noticed that the tag assignment for enemy was actually in reverse, so I changed that. but after tweaking a few more things, I noticed that the collision wasn't actually working, so I decided to print out two bools indicating if either condition was met, with the first being if the colliders were touching, and the second being if the move that was hitting you had already hit you. Both were continuously false, even after I did a move, so I soon realized that one of my colliders was in a child object but the class instance was taken from the collider in the parent object. but the collisions still didn't work and the actual collisions weren't working. Then I went to check on the box colliders and composite colliders in the actual unity UI(both being triggers) but it wouldn't detect anything, and it wouldn't even show up in the contacts tab.
for reference here are what colliders are being used
player1
boxcollider2d not a trigger
compositecollider2d: istrigger
defending hitboxes: boxcollider2d, usedbycomposite
defending hitbox 1,2,3 and 4 boxcollider2d, usedbycomposite
attacking hitbox: boxcollider2d, istrigger
can someone let me know what could be preventing it from detecting contacts?

Comment: nvm i found the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the Is Trigger bool. When it is enabled, Other objects will be able to pass through it as if it does not have a collider.
Their is also different functions for both collision and trigger. the OnCollision functions are used on non Is trigger colliders while if that bool is true, the function is OnTrigger.

Comment: The objects are actually meant to pass through, i set a separate bc2d for the environment collisions that isnt a trigger. the problem is that even though the triggers are supposed to register contacts, they aren't registering them and my Istouching isnt detecting them. the non trigger boxes seem to work perfectly fine though.

Comment: Their is a different function to check triggered and non triggered colliders. The problem vaguely sounds like you need to change all your OnCollision functions to OnTrigger for the triggered colliders. You can have both at the same time if you are re using the script for non triggered objects as well.

Comment: I would like to clarify 2 things. Thr first, being that i am not using any oncollisionenter methods or ontriggerenter methods and only collider.istouching is being used at the moment. Secondly the problem likely is within the collider itself rather than how my code interprets it seeing how even the unity UI doesnt show any contacts on the collider